# How to convert createAlias to jpa specific statement

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a below scenario in my criteria api:

```
            criteria.createAlias("entity1", "cs", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
            criteria.createAlias("cs.entity2", "s", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
            criteria.createAlias("entity3", "p", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
            criteria.createAlias("entity4", "prov", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
            criteria.createAlias("prov.entity5", "cp", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
            criteria.createAlias("prov.entity6", "provDetail",Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Could you please help to convert the above scenario to jpa specific code (or using criteria builder)

Answer (score -2):

To achieve the same scenario using JPA and the Criteria API, you can follow these steps. I'll assume that you have classes representing your entities and an EntityManager to work with. I'll provide an example code snippet that demonstrates how to create the equivalent JPA Criteria API query.

Assuming you have entities named Entity1, Entity2, Entity3, Entity4, Entity5, and Entity6, and you want to create joins similar to the ones in your original code:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;

public class YourJpaCriteriaExample {

    public List<YourResultClass> yourMethod(EntityManager entityManager) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<YourResultClass> query = cb.createQuery(YourResultClass.class);
        Root<Entity1> root = query.from(Entity1.class);

        // Create joins similar to your original code
        Join<Entity1, Entity2> csJoin = root.join("entity2", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Entity1, Entity3> pJoin = root.join("entity3", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Entity1, Entity4> provJoin = root.join("entity4", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Entity4, Entity5> cpJoin = provJoin.join("entity5", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<Entity4, Entity6> provDetailJoin = provJoin.join("entity6", JoinType.LEFT);

        // Add your additional criteria or select the fields you need

        // YourResultClass is a placeholder for the result class you want to select.
        // You need to replace it with your actual result class or use Object[] if needed.
        query.select(/* specify your selection here */);

        TypedQuery<YourResultClass> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Please replace YourResultClass with the actual class or projection you want to select in your query. This code creates a CriteriaQuery with the desired left joins and allows you to select the necessary fields or construct the result class you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in  criteria.createAlias query come some thing  like this "left outer join table2 cp5_ on prov4_.cp_id=cp5_.cp_id ".without addding any condition